# Check if a meeting in outlook is already accepted

Tags: vba, outlook

Good morning. I have a project, and that project consists of made a plan for car location between many people. The aim is to allow the car to those whose the task to do with this have priority. So to do this, when they plan a meeting with a person (the car), my vba code must identify the person(s) who have priority, and respond 'yes' to them, and 'no' to the others. My vba code get all the calendar meetingsitem and plan them.

The problem is that when a meeting is refused, it disappear from the calendar and when it is accepted, it stay. I want to know if a meetingitem is already accepted or not, to avoid to plan it again.

the collectionItem.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, bool) method don't allow to do this. I have tried ResponseStatus but I don't understand when it works. Please help!

Comment: But if a user accepts or rejects an appointment, the MeetingItem object from the Inbox is deleted. If you still have MeetingItem, the user has no responded yet.

Comment: But it not disappear from the calendar

Comment: If an appointment is accepted. If you decline an appointment, it is gone from the Calendar folder,. Is that not what you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when it is accepted, it stay.

The [ResponseStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff867297.aspx) property of the AppointmentItem class returns an `OlResponseStatus` constant indicating the overall status of the meeting for the current user for the appointment. See the [OlResponseStatus Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868658.aspx) for possible values.

Comment: Is the response status set if they decline without sending response?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, and that is thanks to you. The link help me to use ResponseStatus. I'm stupid it was so easy that is the code:

```
Dim oAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

For Each oAppointmentItem In oAppointments.Items
        dDate = DateValue(oAppointmentItem.Start)
        If dDate = DateValue(Date) Then
               //line I want is the next
            If (oAppointmentItem.ResponseStatus = olResponseAccepted) Then
            Else
                If ItemExist(listDestZone, oAppointmentItem.Location) Then
                    Set varDestZone = listDestZone.Item(oAppointmentItem.Location)

                Select Case varDestZone.zone
                    Case zone1: MeetingsZone1.Add oAppointmentItem
                    Case zone2: MeetingsZone2.Add oAppointmentItem
                    Case zone3: MeetingsZone3.Add oAppointmentItem
                    Case zone4: MeetingsZone4.Add oAppointmentItem
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Thanks